# WPF AutoCompleteBox Width based on Content

Tags: wpf, silverlight, autocompletebox

I have an System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox with a fixed width.
The width should dynamically grow based on the content.

How can I achieve this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Set `Width="Auto"` doesn't help?

Comment: Or set the  `MinWidth` property?

Comment: No sry i allready try it. When i use it, the width in the dropdown list stay like the usual width, only when i click the content and its in the field, then the width is set to the content but not in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by placing the `AutoCompleteBox` in a `Grid.Column` with `Width="Auto"`. Here's an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="30" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox />
</Grid>
```